# How to not load certain elements based on screen size with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ads, responsive-design

I am making a site using responsive web design (via media queries).

I want to have different ads for different screen sizes. For example, I don't want a 780by90 ad to be displayed when a phone browser visits the site.

I know that display: none; isn't an option because the ad would still be loaded and record an impression. This is not an option.

Basically, I need to know how to load the ads in via javascript after the screen resolution has been found. I can find the resolution, I just don't know how to add the ads in after finding that.

I have tried .html with jquery but it seems to not allow adding script tags into the dom.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One way would be to append images to to the body with jQuery after the page has loaded, and then transfer those images to the correct portion.  The only problem with this would be that it may take a while for the page to finish loading before it starts loading the image.

Comment: I've sort of solved this problem. If the ads are inserted via an iframe, it is possible to do what I am trying to accomplish. 

Iframes present a few new issues of their own, but they work in particular case to do what's needed.

Answer (score 1):

***CSS3 Media Queries*** will selectively output images based on screen size - as long as the image is referenced in the `CSS`...

Comment: Yes but I need to output entire <script>...</script> blocks, not just images. And with media queries all elements will still be loaded, certain ones just won't be displayed. 

This isn't acceptable with ads because the ad company will register that the ad was loaded when it was never actually displayed to any visitors.

Comment: If you define the ad as a *background image* of a *container* then it should work. The image will be downloaded for the appropriate screen size and *only said image will be requested from the server*...

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing this kind of calculation on the back-end instead of the front-end. You can use libraries such as WURFL or something like Apache Mobile Filter.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using DFP, they have responsive ad functionality built into the googletag object:

https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/3423562?hl=en&ref_topic=4390040

you define ad sizes based on the viewable content area of the browser

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Google DFP [Andyl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3284978/andyl) mentioned their method for responsively displaying ads, which is definitely a good place to start. To this I'd add that you need to define size mappings for **every** slot on the page (even if they're not all responsive) otherwise nothing works properly for some reason.

Also, if you want to hide ad units when the browser is smaller than a given width/height, that Google article suggests **not** defining a mapping for browser size [0, 0]. However, I found when I did this it actually displayed my *largest* creative for some reason. I managed to suppress ads by creating a minimum size mapping that referred to a non-existent creative size, eg.

```
.addSize([0, 0], [1, 1])
```

You can also apply this to any browser size, not just the smallest. I did write [a short post](http://toby1kenobi.com/2014/02/responsive-ad-units-with-google-doubleclick-for-publishers/) about this, although it doesn't have much more information than I've provided here.

Hope this helps,

Toby